# What does each part of this command to grant all privileges mean?

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain the following command?

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Google is the best candidate to answer. Or MySQL manual too

Comment: There's no better explanation than the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Answer (score 2):

- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`

  This gives the user specified later in the command all privileges.

  <sup>http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html</sup>
- `ON *.*`

  Matches everything.
- `TO 'user1'@'localhost'`

  The user with name ‘user1’ on localhost which is to be granted the privileges.
- `WITH GRANT OPTION`

  > The GRANT OPTION privilege enables you to give to other users or remove from other users those privileges that you yourself possess.

  <sup>https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option</sup>